# Playing a cassete whose request is not inside the use_cassete scope using VCR for Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, rspec, vcr

I've built an API (`MyAPI`) that connects to an external API for authentication (`ExAPI`).

For all the requests to MyAPI where the user needs to be authenticated, he sends a cookie with a token that is then sent to ExAPI, and then it gets the user information.

I've recorded a cassete with this request:

```
describe 'VCR-RSpec integration' do
  def make_http_request
    connect = Faraday.new(url: (ENV['EX_API']).to_s) do |faraday|
      faraday.request :url_encoded
      faraday.response :logger 
      faraday.adapter Faraday.default_adapter 
    end
    connect.authorization :Bearer, ENV['USER_TOKEN']
    connect.get('/auth/...')
  end

  skip 'without an explicit cassette name' do
    it 'records an http request' do
      VCR.use_cassette('user_token') do
        expect(make_http_request).to be_success
      end
    end
  end
end
```

So, in my code, if I do a call to `user_stories` it expects a cookie with the `user_token` sends it to the ExAPI and if valid, executes the desired action.

This is how the spec is:

```
describe UserStoriesController, type: :controller do
  before(:each) do
    set_cookies
  end

  context do
    let!(:user) {
      FactoryGirl.create(:user)
    }
    let!(:some_user_stories) {
      FactoryGirl.create_list(:user_story, 3, user: user)
    }

    describe 'GET index' do
      it 'returns a successful 200 response' do
        VCR.use_cassette('user_token') do
          get :index
          expect(response).to be_success
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The problem is that the cassete is not used (I'm assuming that it's because the code to connect to the ExAPI is not inside the `VCR.use_cassete` scope, but in a method inside the controller.

Is that a way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, my mistake. I forgot to initialize VCR:

```
VCR.configure do |config|
  config.cassette_library_dir = "fixtures/vcr_cassettes"
  config.hook_into :webmock
end
```